# exchange server 2007 - public folder - connect to from remote location

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders

I am not sure if this is possible and cant seem to find any information but what I would like to know about is;

I am in the UK and have exchange server 2007. I have remote users in Germany. They are not that keen on OWA and would like to know if they can link to a public folder on our exchange from their Outlook client.

Is this possible at all? Any links / advise would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like they don't have another Exchange Server computer there. If they do, there's a different set of questions and answers for your issue.

Assuming they do not, you can use HTTP-over-RPC (aka "Outlook Anywhere") to give them "full blown Outlook" access to your Exchange Server computer, or you can use a VPN.

Have a look at:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998934.aspx

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer but thanks to other for taking the time to look! :)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.  If they're currently using Outlook, then in the folders view, they'll see a top level choice of "All Public Folders".  They can drill down into that tree view and select the folders they want.

They may want to add some of those folders as their favorites, which can be set up to synchronize public folder so they can be worked on offline.

Answer (score 0):

Are the German users using the same mailbox server as your UK users, or do they have their own server?  If they've got their own, is it in the same AD domain, or a separate one?  And finally, if they're in a separate domain, is there any kind of trust relationship between it and yours?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if they are part of your network.  As long as they can browse to the folder with Windows Explorer this will work.

We run Outlook at my office and do not use Exchange, but we do host the pst's in a network folder.  I accomplished this by setting up Outlook on each machine and then moving the pst to the network.  When Outlook is started again it will prompt you to browse for the location of the pst.

If the remote users arent part of your domain this may not be possible...or it may be possible with something like Hamachi (which is free).